# How do I recursively flatten a nested list of loops with outer lists first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, recursion

For example, given a list like `[[[1]]],[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7]`, the output should not be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, but should instead be `[5,7,2,3,4,6,1]`.

Here is what I have now:

```
def foo (intlist, result):
    for item in intlist:
        if (type(item) == int):
            result.append(item)
            intlist.remove(item)
        else:
            --------- 
    for item in intlist:
        foo(intlist, result)
    return result
```

I am not sure how to verify if the list only contains `list`s and no `int`s on the side for the else statement.

Comment: You need to recursively check if ```item``` has any ```ints``` or not

Answer (score 1):

You can make this recursive, so that each depth of recursion unpacks the corresponding depth list.

```
def foo(intlist, result):
    if not intlist:
        return
    temp = []
    for item in intlist:
        if type(item) != list:
            result.append(item)
        else:
            for i in item:
                temp.append(i)
    intlist = temp
    foo(intlist, result)

your_list = []
result = []
foo(your_list, result)
print(result)   # outputs [5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6]
```

Comment: this would only work on a nested list of ints, it should work on a nested list of any data. you can do this by checking for `list` instead of worrying about `int`.

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned ```intlist```, that's why. Incorporated your suggestion @Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a nice use-case for python's wonderful generators -

```py
def preorder (ls):
  if not ls:
    return
  elif isinstance(ls[0], list):
    yield from preorder(ls[1:] + ls[0])
  else:
    yield ls[0]
    yield from preorder(ls[1:])

input = [[[[1]]],[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7]
result = list(preorder(input))
print(result)
# [5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1]
```

Here's what the evaluation looks like -

```py
[[[[1]]],[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7]
[[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7] + [[[1]]]
[[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7,[[1]]]
[5,[[6]],7,[[1]]] + [2,3,4]
[5,[[6]],7,[[1]],2,3,4]
5                                # yield
[[[6]],7,[[1]],2,3,4]
[7,[[1]],2,3,4] + [[6]]
[7,[[1]],2,3,4,[6]]
7                                # yield
[[[1]],2,3,4,[6]]
[2,3,4,[6]] + [[1]]
[2,3,4,[6],[1]]
2                                # yield
3                                # yield
4                                # yield
[[6],[1]]
[[1]] + [6]
[[1],6]
[6] + [1]
[6,1]
6                                # yield
1                                # yield
```

Or you can eagerly compute the result using the same logical recursion structure -

```py
def preorder (ls):
  if not ls:
    return []
  elif isinstance(ls[0], list):
    return preorder(ls[1:] + ls[0])
  else:
    return [ ls[0], *preorder(ls[1:]) ]

input = [[[[1]]],[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7]
result = preorder(input)
print(result)
# [5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach. Here, the lists are concatenated then passed to the next level.

```
lst = [[[[1]]],[2,3,4],5,[[6]],7]

def foo (intlist, result):
    tmp = []
    for item in intlist:
        if (type(item) == list):
            tmp.extend(item)  # pass list to next level
        else:
            result.append(item)  # add item to result
    if len(tmp): 
        foo(tmp, result) # go to next level
    return result

result = foo(lst, [])
print(result)  # [5,7,2,3,4,6,1]
```